# Can I replace the glass mirror in my (wing) mirror?

Tags: electrical, paint, replace, parts

A neighbour of mine hit my (wing) mirror with a [sliotar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliotar) and it's cracked/smashed.

**Can I replace just the glass** (the actual mirror itself)?
Preferably doing it myself.
As oppposed to having to buy a spare mirror and have it painted?

#### Details:

- **Make:** Volkswagen
- **Model:** Bora *(Comfort Line)*
- **Year:** 2002
- **Electric Mirrors: `Yes`**
- **Name:** Borat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too bad, around here any auto parts shop can sell you a universal mirror glass and you can glue it on top of the broken glass.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. It is only costing me €10

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. By far the easiest is to go to a scrapyard and buy one, take it apart and replace the glass.

Straightforward on most cars.

Comment: So I still have to buy the whole mirror?! Damn. How should I take the glass out of my current one?